# The limitation of $G$ and loop group $\Omega G$ in Atiyah's and Donaldson's work on Instantons

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, quantum-field-theory

In [Atiyah's work [Ref. 1]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01212288), Atiyah states that "Essentially we shall show (at least for $G$ a classical
group and probably for all $G$) that Yang-Mills instantons in 4D can be naturally identified with (i.e. have the same parameter space as) the instantons in 2D for the theory in which the complex projective $n$-space $CP_n$, is replaced by the infinite-dimensional manifold ($\Omega G$ of loops on the structure group $G$."

> Question (1): What is the precise restriction of $G$ in Atiyah's on Instantons in 2D and in 4D? Must $G$ be simple compact Lie groups?
>   Or must $G$ be classical groups? Or how general the $G$ can be?

---

In [Atiyah's work [Ref. 1]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01212288), he also mentions that [Donaldson's work [Ref. 2]](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103941177) gives the
proof only for the classical groups but it seems likely that his result holds for all $G$.

> Question (2): What is the precise restriction of $G$ in Donaldson's work here? Must $G$ be simple compact Lie groups?
>   Or must $G$ be classical groups? Or how general the $G$ can be?
>
> Question (3): The instanton study here in 2D for Atiyah's theory in which the complex projective $n$-space $CP_n$, is replaced by the infinite-dimensional manifold ($\Omega G$ of loops on the structure group $G$.) How is this story of $CP_n$ v.s. $\Omega G=\Omega SU(n)$ here related to the $G=SU(n)$-Yang Mills theory? Here $CP_n$ is finite $n$-dimensional complex manifold, while $\Omega G$ is said to be infinite-dimensional.

---

Refs:

1. Instantons In Two-dimensions And Four-dimensions, 1984 - 15 pages Commun.Math.Phys. 93 (1984) 437-451,  M.F. Atiyah
2. Instantons and geometric invariant theory, Comm. Math. Phys. Volume 93, Number 4 (1984), 453-460. S. K. Donaldson

---

Note: Classical groups are defined as the special linear groups over the reals R, the complex numbers C and the quaternions H together with special automorphism groups of symmetric or skew-symmetric bilinear forms and Hermitian or skew-Hermitian sesquilinear forms defined on real, complex and quaternionic finite-dimensional vector spaces

Comment: Donaldson's proof uses the ADHM construction in an essential way. I do not know a version of the ADHM construction for groups other than the classical groups, but perhaps that is my ignorance speaking. I would be glad to learn that is the case. Perhaps there is a proof that works more generally following the analytical ideas he mentions but does not pursue.

Comment: @ArunDebray I see you have suggested [the synonym (qft) $\to$ (quantum-field-theory)](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/quantum-field-theory/synonyms). Perhaps mentioning this synonym also in [the designated thread on meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/194) might attract more users who can vote on
(I am aware that this is not related to the topic of the question - but since this was the question where the (qft) tag was created, it seemed like a reasonable place to mention this. If needed, we can continue this discussion [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2018/10/29).)